# Can static variable in Activity save its state?

Tags: android

Let's assume i've got standard activity with one variable, boolean, for example:

```
public class My Activity extends Activity {
    public static boolean A = true;
}
```

I initialize it immidietly and its value will change during runtime. Are there some troubles with this kind of variable initialization and Activity lifecycle. Can this boolean A return its initial value during onPause, onStop or other lifecycle methods? How it corresponds with onCreate()?

Comment: you will loose the static variable when the activity is destroyed . use the onSaveInstanceState() to save data you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The (static) variable is inizialized **before** the constructor runs, so it will stay there for all the lifecicle of the activity.
The problem is that if the activity is destroyed and recreated (for instancce, when you rotate the screen): in this case you loose all the state of the class.
One solution is to save the activity state with the method `onSaveInstanceState()`, and retrieve it in the `onCreate()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You use `yield` keyword with return. For example,

```
yield return A;
```

Read more on keyword `yield` on web.

Answer (score 0):

I think that variable A lives as well as your class lifecycle but not the activity lifecycle . onPause() means that the activity is pausing but your class is still alive so A too. I think it remains alive between onCreate and onDestroy...